# running a text file of inserts in parallel in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I need to bulk load data into a table with user defined types but see that user defined types are not supported in the bulk loader. I was thinking, if I wrote every row as an insert statement (50million) into a text file, could I load the text file of insert statements in parallel?

Right now I'm simply using the copy command to load the data but and getting about 2,500 rows/sec so loading 60million records is quite slow.

Trying to figure out what the fastest way to load data the data would be if I can't use the bulkload utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own program by usind Cassandras [asynchronous queries](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/asynchronous_t.html), Datastax provides drivers for pretty much any popular language.

Comment: Thanks @Will! Just made it edit as I'm trying to use python to do this but am running into some issue as this is my first time using python...